# Javascript field validation not working properly

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am developing a web application in which I have created a form and in the onSubmit event of the form I have called a java script function which will check for "Field must not left blank" condition if it is left blank the form must not be posted so I have written following code:

Jsp Page Form

```
<form action="Result.jsp" name="validityCheck" onsubmit="return fnCheckEmptyField();">

<input type="text" name="txtIIDN" id="txtIIDN" style="font-size:medium;" onkeypress="return fnKeyPress(event)"/>


<input type="submit" id="btnValidityCheck" value="Check Validity" />
</form>
```

Javascript code is as follows

```
<script>
function fnCheckEmptyField()
    {
        var strDomain= document.getElementsByName("txtIIDN").value;
        if(strDomain == null)
        {
            document.getElementById("lblValidityStatus").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("lblValidityStatus").innerHTML="Domain Name Field Can't be Left Blank";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

When I try to submit the form the javascript function gets executed and then form will gets posted whether the return value is true or false.
I dont want to submit the form when the return value is false i.e when field is empty

and also the condition in onsubmit event onsubmit="return fnCheckEmptyField(); showing me an error
**Cannot return from outside a function or method.**

Can you figure out what is the mistake I am commiting and possible solution for that?

Comment: remove form action in jsp and if function returns true then add action to the particular form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onsubmit event on the form and In the submit button HTML, put this

```
   <input type="submit" id="btnValidityCheck" value="Check Validity" onclick="return fnCheckEmptyField();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what Furqan said, you should probably use the button and an onclick event to check the form, and if the form is valid, then call .submit() on your form.

I tend to not even use a submit button, I just have a normal button, and have it run javascript... then the javascript submits the form.

Example (HTML submit button):

```
<button id="btnValidityCheck" value="Check Validity" onclick="return fnCheckEmptyField();">Click Here</button>
```

Javascript function:

```
function fnCheckEmptyField() {
   var strDomain= document.getElementsByName("txtIIDN").value;
   if(strDomain == "") {
      document.getElementById("lblValidityStatus").innerHTML="Domain Name Field Can't be Left Blank";
   }
   else {
      document.getElementById("myFormId").submit();
   }
}
```

Notice that if the javascript feel that the form is valid, THEN it will submit your form.  You need to define an id for your form tag for this to work.

Also, I changed the == null check to == ""... that may have been causing issues...

Cheers!

Comment: actually null is working fine with it ..... and also function gets executed but the problem is after function execution the form is getting posted so because of this main objective of not submitting the form or not traversing to next page is not achieved

Comment: there might be the something in the error message shown on the onSubmit event the same is displayed on the onClick event  onsubmit="return fnCheckEmptyField(); showing me an error Cannot return from outside a function or method.

Comment: What my codes does is this: it won't submit the form until it KNOWS that it is valid... instead of trying to cancel a form submission.